# What is ZCV curve in a lithium ion battery?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

What is the relation of impedance, capacity and voltage in a lithium ion battery?

Comment: [Site guidance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): *Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!*

Comment: Since you have 3 independent variables, think of it as a surface rather than a curve.

Comment: _think of it as a surface rather than a curve_. Not really: since there is no relationship between the 3 variables, there is no single curve to represent their relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 parameters, so I'll take 2 at a time.

> Impedance and capacity

For a given battery as it ages: none.

Over time and cycles (over months) the capacity decreases and the internal resistance increases. However, there is no direct relationship between loss of capacity and increase of resistance.

For various new batteries of a given technology: the impedance is inversely proportional to the battery energy. That is, a 1 kWh battery has twice the impedance of a 2 kWh battery.

For various new or aging batteries of a different technologies: no way to know.

(I assume you really do mean "capacity" and not "State of Charge". Both can be measured in Ah, but they are very different parameters.)

> Impedance and voltage

Two answers, depending on whether you mean "Open Circuit Voltage" (OCV) or terminal voltage.

OCV: none directly. OCV and impedance do not affect each other. However, SoC affects both.

Terminal voltage: none directly. Terminal voltage and impedance do not affect each other. However, SoC (State of Charge), current, and past history, affect both.

> capacity and voltage

None. Neither the OCV nor the terminal voltage are affected by the capacity. However, as the cell gets old, and capacity fades, the resistance also increases. Therefore, under load, the terminal voltage of an old cell sags more than for a new cell. The OCV is not affected.

In conclusion:

> What is ZCV curve in a lithium ion battery?

There isn't one and there is no direct relationship between these three parameters.

Answer (score 0):

What is the ZVC curve for any battery?  Where is it?  This is  rhetorical presumptive question as there is no 3 dimensional curve.

But there are some general truths to behaviours.  Like electrolytic caps, if you were a battery design engineer, there may be formula for choosing geometric cell sizes, electrode gaps and process/quality control yields with material choices, an Engineer could compute the ZVC properties. Cell sizes tend to be small for production safety reasons and constructed in modules with safety mechanisms.

https://www.batterypowertips.com/how-to-read-battery-discharge-curves-faq/

- Impedance Z, tends to have lower ESR with higher capacity batteries.
- more directly Z is inverse with the C charge and discharge rates from self-heating.
- Cells in series have ESR that adds with voltage for each cell

  - but the Ah capacity does not change and remains the capacity of the weakest cell in series